# Null value on combobox - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, combobox

I want to get nim from database using combobox but my combobox not show anything

**My controler**

```
public function add(){

    // Ambil data perusahaan dari tabel perusahaan
        //$this->Super_Model->get('t_mynetpoin');
        $data['nim'] =  $this->Super_Model->query('select nim from t_mynetpoin');
        // End of Ambil Data perusahaan
        $data['view']= 'v_super_admin/super_admin_template/v_sidebar';
        $data['view']= 'v_super_admin/Coin/v_form';
        $this->load->view('index',$data);

}
```

**My model**

```
public function query($sql=''){
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query){
  return $query->result();
}else{
  return print_r($this->db->last_query());
}
```

**My Combobox In View**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nim  </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<?php echo form_dropdown("nim", $nim, @$row->nim, 'class="form-control" id="nim"'); ?>  
</div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

**My Table Structure**

```
|id_mynetpoin|tot_poin|last_modified|nim       |
|1           |7000    |2016-05-20   |1314115315|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->result();
```

this will return array of objects while for dropdown you will need an array with key value pair
so run a loop and coveret your result simmilar to below array,

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');


https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html
```

In your controller,
    Instead of below line

**updated**
    $data['nim'] = $this->Super_Model->query('select nim from t_mynetpoin');
write below code

```
$result =  $this->Super_Model->query('select nim from t_mynetpoin');
        $options = array();
        foreach ($result as $r){
        $options []= $r->nim;
        }
        $data['nim'] = $options;
```

Comment: hmm, how to get data from database ?

Comment: i'v do that in my model

Comment: what is your table structure ?

Comment: i've Updated my question add table structure

Comment: check if $nim has value in view by var_dump or print_r

Comment: i've been chek is null in value $nim